# Intellij plugin to count operation or cpu cycles in tests

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I'm looking for JAVA cpu cycles counter.

- I want to run test and see that it invoke some 2321 operations/cpuCycles, then optimize my code and see 3515 operations. So that I knew that I made mistake.
- each time I will run the test it will have always same value until I modify the code.

Is there any feature that can help me with this?

Regards.

Comment: Google for "Java CPU profiler". See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/09/intellij-idea-2018-3-eap-git-submodules-jvm-profiler-macos-and-linux-and-more/.

Answer (score 0):

Number of operations does not tell you anything. I advise you consider JMH framework which is designed for micro-benchmarking java methods so you can run two implementations and compare time and memory consumption.

There is library description

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Introducton from author

https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/

Detailed samples (open files one by one and read comments)

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/

And there is IJ plugin (though, its usefulness is under the question)

https://github.com/artyushov/idea-jmh-plugin